# Capture high fps video from usb camera

Tags: opencv, frame-rate

Just got this USB camera from amazon : [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00KA7WSSU/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o02_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00KA7WSSU)

Am using opencv and I have a USB camera that supports 640(H) * 480(V) pixels with MJPEG format @ 120fps.

How can I use the camera to capture high fps frames for robotic application. I want to do run machine learning models on high speed moving object (lets say 1 meter/second)

Tried the following but no use, still getting fps of 30 and resolution is also remaining high

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 120)
```

I have tried to save the video frame but its not working on mac i.e. vlc is unable to open the file.

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG')
print (fourcc)
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.mp4',fourcc, 120, (640,480))
```

Comment: Can you play back the video with OpenCV?

Comment: 120 fps mjpg encoding or even rendering isn't trivial, since you only have 8.33 ms for processing each frame, including the decoding etc. I would suggest to test functionality to capture like 1000 images to memory without further processing, then stop capturing and write them to disk "offline". If you capture for example a digital  clock, you can visually analyze the captured fps afterwards. When you made sure that 120 fps capturing works you should pipeline your live video recording by task parallelism and some buffers in between.

Comment: What kind of camera do you use?

Comment: what does cap.get return for fps and resolution?

Comment: do the set commands return true or false?

Comment: cap.get returns 30 fps

Comment: Not all cameras support these custom parameters. The amazon product description states it's a 30 fps camera with a seemingly fixed resolution.